# replace asterisk innerhtml javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how do i replace the asterisks with a blank ("") in the innerhtml using javascript?
i have tried this.

```
document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lab").innerHTML.replace(/&#42;/g, '');
```

and i also tried doing the asterisk itself but it gets commented..
searched everywhere i can't seem to find ways to remove the appended in innerhtml aside from replacing it with a blank.. are there any other options?
i also tried searching for ways to use replace and other options. for added info i am using this for the validation of a form
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the asterisk:

```
.....replace(/\*/g, "")
```

because it is a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: thank you very much i forgot how to escape characters